# How to catch errors or exceptions in Csh?

Tags: linux, shell, csh

I would like to know if there is a way to catch the exceptions and control the flow when this happen.
For example running this line, I would like to know if a shell error occurred .

```
source /scripts/scriptThatWillFail.csh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exit/return code is stored in the `status` variable in C shell.

```
source /scripts/scriptThatWillFail.csh
if ($status != 0) then
    echo failed
else
    echo passed
endif
```